# Anyway to use javascript to modify css/style and save the changes to a cached css file

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have bunch of code that minifies, shrinks/expands, changes widths all that goodness client side with via javascript. What I would like to do though is save the style changes to the cached css file so they dont have to be recalculated everytime the page changes.

Is there any way to do this? Browser dependent would be fine too.

Comment: You can post it to server via ajax http post and then add to new pages as usual. You can do it more correctly if specify special api to affect that generated css. I understand that this is not exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Why does it modify so much with JS? There may be a better method overall.

Comment: @dimitry i was hoping to avoid that just because the number of css files that would be stored but this might actually be the best solution (if there is a solution).

Comment: @popnoodles Some of the stuff is goofy, like when extra li tags are added to a ul from some server side code, i recalculate the widths and what not to accomodate them fluidly. calc() or something similar might available to ahndle this but i dont know enough about it.

Comment: It sounds like your CSS should be rewritten such that it handles that without any .calc or other maths. Most things can be achieved with regular CSS, including evenly-spaced horizontal lists.